# How to apply global transformation to child object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to apply a global position (from a WebVR controller) to the child object of a parent that has several transformations. It's not a first generation child, though there aren't any transformations applied to any of the object in between:

**Scene**
  ¦
  ¦
**Object** (with transformations)
  ¦
  ¦
**Object** (no transformations)
  ¦
  ¦
**Child** (*cube*) (Where I want to apply a global position)

If I apply these transformations to a cube that's a direct child of the scene, it works fine:

```
cube.position.copy(globalPosition);
```

But I need to apply it to the child object. I've tried to convert the global position to the local one by doing:

```
const worldToLocal = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(cube.parent.matrixWorld);
cube.position.copy(globalPosition);
cube.applyMatrix(worldToLocal);
```

But the cube is not in the same position as if it were a child of the scene. Not sure what else to try, thanks for the help!

Comment: I you apply the resulting transformation of the hierarchy you need either need to remove all transformations upwards until the root, or attach the cube directly to the scene, otherwise the cube will be transformed twice.

Comment: @AlbertoElias Is this what you are trying to do? `cube.position.copy( globalPosition ); cube.worldToLocal( cube.position );`

Comment: @philipp Yes, that's what I've been trying to figure out, but when attaching the cube to the root, the cube's previous parent started acting weird. That was actually what I was doing the first time I confronted this problem, but it stopped working

Comment: @WestLangley Yes! That's it, though I need to do `cube.parent.worldToLocal`, and I actually need to do the same for the rotation, so I ended up using matrices like I explain in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got stuck with this issue a long time ago, and ended up grouping it differently and making `cube` a direct child of the `scene` and that seemed to work at the time, but now, `cube`'s previous parents started acting weird, they would rotate to a strange position and not move if I tried to change their position or rotation. That's why I know wanted to fix it properly.

So I ended up doing something similar to what @WestLangley mentioned, but I also need to transform the rotation, so I used matrices:

```
const worldToLocal = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(cube.parent.matrixWorld);
const poseMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
poseMatrix.makeRotationFromQuaternion(globalQuaternion);
poseMatrix.setPosition(globalPosition);
poseMatrix.multiplyMatrices(worldToLocal, poseMatrix);
poseMatrix.decompose(cube.position, cube.quaternion, {});
```

Thanks a lot for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Good day everyone! I advice to regroup your meshes. If you want to change position in world of all group, you need to apply position on parent object, transform use on child objects. For grouping try to use empty mesh and use method parentMesh.add(childMesh). Hope this help's ;)

Comment: I only wanted to apply the transformations on the child object as if it was a global object. I ended up doing what I mentioned in my answer. Thanks!